# Issue with OAUTH in Rails 4 using Spotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise, omniauth

Been stuck for a couple days now.  Devise, Omniauth, Spotify.  I'm trying to allow users to signin/signup with spotify.  It says my redirect URI is invalid, but I have set that to 
    'http://localhost:3000/users/auth/spotify/callback/' 
on the spotify website.

Here's the error... for some reasons it is doing 2 omniauth requests which may be because I have gem 'omniauth' and gem 'omniauth-oauth2' which I'll show below.

```
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:31 -0500
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:31 -0500
I, [2015-04-09T10:20:31.062564 #63684]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.

Started GET "/users/auth/spotify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:34 -0500
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:34 -0500
I, [2015-04-09T10:20:34.782951 #63684]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.

Started GET "/users/auth/spotify/callback?code=STUFF&state=MORESTUFF" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:36 -0500
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify/callback?code=MOREMORESTUFF" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:20:36 -0500
I, [2015-04-09T10:20:36.669918 #63684]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2015-04-09T10:20:37.468309 #63684] ERROR -- omniauth: (spotify) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Invalid redirect URI
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid redirect URI"}
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"HAHAGOTYA", "state"=>"NOSEEUM"}
  Parameters: {"code"=>"BYEBYE", "state"=>"BYEBYEBYE"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 6ms
Completed 302 Found in 6ms
```

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'bson', '~> 2.2'
gem 'moped', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.2.2'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-spotify'
gem 'devise'
```

Routes

```
devise_for :users, :controller => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}
root 'users#index'
```

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  #include Mongoid::Paperclip
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
     :omniauth_providers => [:spotify, :facebook]

  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
      field :reset_password_token,   type: String
      field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String


  field :provider, type: String
  field :uid, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :posts
  embeds_many :workouts
  embeds_many :routines
  embeds_many :meals
  has_many :followers
  has_many :followings


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end

end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def spotify
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

Now, contrary to what I've read, I have both the config/initializers/omniauth.rb and config/initializers/devise.rb configuration for the spotify secret and key.  Part of me thinks this may be what is breaking everything, because it's initializing the request twice.

Anyway here's devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :spotify, ENV['SPOTIFY_ID'], ENV['SPOTIFY_KEY'], provider_ignores_state: true
```

and omniauth.rb

```
  provider :spotify, ENV["SPOTIFY_ID"], ENV["SPOTIFY_KEY"], :provider_ignores_state => true
    {
      :scope => "playlist-read-private, playlist-modify-public, playlist-modify-private"
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can provide more info if needed.

---

### UPDATE

I've removed :provider_ignore_state, and am now getting

```
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify/callback?code=WUPSstate=WUPS" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:53:55 -0500
Started GET "/users/auth/spotify/callback?code=WUPS&state=WUPS" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 10:53:55 -0500
I, [2015-04-09T10:53:55.732722 #64694]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2015-04-09T10:53:55.733274 #64694] ERROR -- omniauth: (spotify)     Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

I've also changed session_store.rb to include

```
domain: localhost:3000
```

and application_controller.rb

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Comment: the gem 'omniauth-spotify' caused a lot of pain for me with such behaviour. Use gem 'rspotify' instead and you will be fine :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting exactly the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue in onmniauth. See here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81

Forking the gem and changing the dependency works. You can use my fork which fixes this for now...

See commit:
https://github.com/morgz/rspotify/commit/969d208770e407526c03edea81c3c686e9b79705

https://github.com/morgz/rspotify